# I'm looking for a word that means "something must occur with another thing"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that means that something must occur with another thing. Almost as though it is mutually inclusive, however it **must** happen with another. Anyone know?

Sample sentence:

> Tomatoes in a salad are not ______, salads don't have to have tomatoes.

I considered *mutually inclusive*, but *mutually inclusive* does not mean that it necessarily has to be together and that's what I'm looking to say. I'm writing a speech for a debate about immigration and I'm attempting to say that immigration from our Southern borders and crime are not together all the time and that Sanctuary cities don't facilitate drug problems and prostitution because they do not question immigration status. Like salads and tomatoes don't necessarily go hand in hand.

Comment: Why exactly does ***mutually inclusive*** not work in that situation? Are you trying to find a single word/phrase that says something is neither mutually inclusive nor mutually exclusive? Could you say "not required"?

Comment: Looks like "required" would fit perfectly well in that example and meets your definition.

Comment: I thought about mutually inclusive, but mutually inclusive does not mean that it necessarily has to be together and that's what I'm looking to say. I'm writing a speech for a debate about immigration and I'm attempting to say that immigration from our Southern borders and crime are not together all the time and that Sanctuary cities don't facilitate drug problems and prostitution because they do not question immigration status. Like salads and tomatoes don't necessarily go hand in hand.

Comment: uh, "necessary"?

Comment: *required*, *mandatory*, *necessary*, *obligatory*. Use a thesaurus...

Comment: You can have *unrelated* problems, or they can be said to be *orthogonal*. You are trying to refute an *ad hominem* argument in your speech. I think you are describing some kind of *guilt by association*. See also [conflating the issues](https://thebettereditor.wordpress.com/2012/04/13/conflating-the-issues/).

Comment: Essential is the word. It perfectly suits

Comment: You are talking about cause and effect. You are arguing that sanctuary cities don't cause drug problems and prostitution.

Answer (score 6):

You could use **[requisite](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/requisite)** in the following way.

> Tomatoes are not requisite for a proper salad.

The adjective definition is:

> required or necessary for a particular purpose, position, etc.; indispensable:

with the noun form referencing that:

> something requisite; a necessary quality, thing, etc.

Answer (score 6):

> Tomatoes are not ***vital/essential/indispensable*** in a salad; salads don't
>   have to have tomatoes.

ODO:

> **[vital](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/vital)**
>   *ADJECTIVE*
>
> **1** Absolutely necessary or important; essential.
>
> ‘Each player assumes a specific role that is vital to the overall team
>   framework.’
>
> **[essential](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/essential)**
>   *ADJECTIVE*
>
> **1** Absolutely necessary; extremely important.
>
> ‘fiber is an essential ingredient’
>
> **[indispensable](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/indispensable)**
>   *ADJECTIVE*
>
> Absolutely necessary.
>
> ‘The horse is an indispensable character to most stories of Chinese
>   warriors.’

Answer (score 4):

Try **concomitant**.

Defined by [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/concomitant) as:

> something that accompanies or is collaterally connected with something else

Also see below the definition by [Cambridge dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/concomitant).

> something that happens with something else and is connected with it

Comment: A perfectly good word, but one that will be unclear to many readers.

Comment: ^^ thought this word when I read title to question

Answer (score 2):

You have the answer in your question!

> Immigration from our Southern borders and crime do not **necessarily** go
>   together.
>
> Sanctuary cities don't **necessarily** facilitate drug problems and
>   prostitution just because they do not question immigration status.

Forget about the sample sentence with the tomatoes.  Several words, for example, *obligatory*, could go in the blank, but they wouldn't help you with your real concern.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm looking for a word that means “something must occur with another
>   thing

It depends on the viewpoint and whether there are dependencies at work. Your title, sample sentence, and context are all different in these respects. Salads don't depend on tomatoes - tomato isn't **obligatory**.

In you immigration example, It appears you are trying to argue that crime and immigrants don't **go hand in hand**. Unlike the salad, you are looking at the situation from an outside perspective.

If you want the analogy to succeed, I think you need to make it more parallel to the actual situation so as not to open yourself up to counterarguments in the debate.

**obligatory**

> 1:  binding in law or conscience

"Obligatory." Merriam-Webster.com. Merriam-Webster, n.d. Web. 17 Feb. 2017.

**go hand in hand**

> if two things go hand in hand, they exist together and are connected
>   with each other (often + with ) Crime usually goes hand in hand with
>   poor economic conditions.

go hand in hand. (n.d.) Cambridge Dictionary of American Idioms. (2006). Retrieved February 17 2017 from http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/go+hand+in+hand

Answer (score 1):

**Prerequisite** is what you're looking for!

Comment: Please add the definition to your answer.

Comment: Preprequisite implies a temporal causality.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase **mutually inclusive** would seem as though it *should* mean this, as opposed to **mutually exclusive** (which categorically means **cannot** occur together). However, it appears that *mutually inclusive* does not bear the weight of necessity and is I've seen definitions which specify that they *can* both occur.

Answer (score 0):

I think the phrase you're looking for is 'mutually assured.'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).